# Spring/Damper Calculation & Plotting

Tags: matlab, plot, simulink, ode45, dsolve

Given two systems with damper/spring:

[image: Systems]

First system's simulink model with step time 2, final value 0.5:

[image]

[image: First system]

Simulink of the second system with same input:

[image]

[image: Second system]

I have to find the code using `dsolve` and `ode45` to generate the same graph with Simulink. Given values are:

```
m1 = 500
c1 = 1200
k1 = 25000
k2 = 15000
m2 = 50
```

I tried to find `dsolve` but it couldn't solve it. So I got to use `ode45`, and I am totally lost.

Differential equation of the first system:

[image: First system DE]

```
syms x(t) y(t) 
Dy = diff(y,t); 
Dx = diff(x,t); 
D2x = diff(x,2,t); 
cond = [x(0)==0, y(0)==0, Dy(0)==0, Dx(0)==5]; 
eqn33 = D2x + (2*0.2121*0.1414*Dx) + (0.1414^2)*x==2*0.2121*0.1414*Dy+(0.1414^2)*y; 
sol33 = dsolve(eqn33,cond) 
pretty(sol33)
```

Comment: What is the question? How to solve this ODE? That's not a programming question.

Comment: The reason `dsolve` can't solve it is because you have two differential variables (`x` and `y`), but only one differential equation.

Comment: The question is, i have to find the graph of the displacement of the both systems as the same as the simulink models. The conditions can vary.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your Simulink model?

Comment: Sure. just uploaded

Comment: Thank you. As I suspected, the Simulink implementation and your symbolic attempts are very different: in the Simulink model, you have a known profile for `y` and `Dy`, i.e. the values of `y` and `Dy` are known for all values of `t` *a priori*. In your symbolic attempt, however, `y` and `Dy` are *unknown* differential variables for which you specify an initial condition at `t=0`. Do you see the difference? So you are not comparing the same thing. I'll edit my answer for the `ode` approach.

Comment: Note also that in your first model, your step input represent the second derivative of `y`, whereas in your second model, it represents `y`, so again you are not comparing like for like.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer updated to match Simulink model implementation**

To use `ode45`, you first need to write a function that computes the derivative of you input vector (i.e. your differential equation), and store that function in a separate file with the function name as the filename. Please note that the ode solvers can only solve first-order differential equations, so you first need to do a bit of work to convert your second-order differential equation to a first-order one. For more details, see the [documentation on `ode45`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8d6eW.jpg).

Based on what you have done in your Simulink model, `D2y` is known for all values of `t` (it's the step input), so we need to integrate it with respect to time to get `Dy` and `y`. So our state vector is `X = [x; Dx; y; Dy]` and our function looks like (stored in `diff_eqn.m`):

```
function dX = diff_eqn(t,X)

m1=500; 
c=1200;
k1=25000; 

dX(1) = X(2); % Dx
dX(2) = -(1/m1)*(c*(X(2)-X(4)/m1) + k1*(X(1)-X(3)/m1));; % D2x
dX(3) = X(4); % Dy

if t<2
  dX(4) = 0; % D2y
else
  dX(4) = 0.5;
end
```

as `dX = [Dx; D2x; Dy; D2y]`.

In your script or your MATLAB command window, you can then call the ode solver (initial conditions all being equal to zero for `Dx`, `x`, `Dy` and `y`, as per your Simulink model):

```
[t,X] = ode45(@diff_eqn,[0 20],[0; 0; 0; 0]);
```

Adjust the `ode` solver options (e.g. max step size, etc...) to get results with more data points. To get the same plot as in your Simulink model, you can then process the results from the `ode` solver:

```
D2x = diff(X(:,2))./diff(t);
D2x = [0; D2x];
D2y = zeros(size(D2x));
D2y(t>=2) = 0.5;
plot(t,[D2y 500*D2x])
grid on
xlabel('Time [s]')
legend('D2y','m1*D2x','Location','NorthEast')
```

Which gives the following plot, matching the results from your Simulink model:

[image]

Comment: I used dsolve  
clc, clear all
m1=500;
m2=50;
c=1200
k1=25000;
k2=15000;
wn=sqrt(k1/m1);
z=c/2*sqrt(k1*m1);
syms x t
eqn1=dsolve('D2x+2*z*wn*Dx+x*wn^2','Dx(0)=0','D(0)=0')
pretty(eqn1)
syms y t
eqn2=dsolve('2*z*wn*Dy+y*wn^2','Dy(0)==0')
pretty(eqn2) but i don't know how to combine these two solutions and to plot the graph

Comment: See my edited answer. But it assume that the 2 equations between `x` and `y` are decoupled, which is not true. The root of the problem is you don't have enough equations for the number of variables.

Comment: Edited answer based on Simulink implementation, but something's not right, so you're not telling us everything.

Comment: sorry for a late comment, those are all zero for four integrator blocks and the gain blocks for the y and Dy are 1/500 which are 1/m

Comment: That doesn't match what your symbolic attempt does, but I will update my answer nonetheless. The results now match the Simulink model. I'll also delete the previous part of my answer based on your incomplete question, as they are irrelevant.

Comment: Use a similar approach for the more complex model

Comment: sorry i was in abroad! your second matlab graph is the same as the graph from simulink i've got for the first model

Comment: Yes, because as I said, I used the same equations and initial conditions as in your Simulink model. You can use a similar approach for the more complex model. Your symbolic attempt, however, is completely different. If that answers your question (I believe it does), please accept my answer.

Comment: I have a question, in the function script, dX(2), how did you get -(1/m1)*(c*(X(2)-X(4)/m1) + k1*(X(1)-X(3)/m1))? instead of -(1/m1)*(c*(X(2)-X(4))+(k1/m1)*(X(1)-X(3)) ?  The basic function is m(d^2x/dx^2)=-kx-c(dx/dt)+ky+c(dy/dt) isnt it?

Comment: Also, isnt that dX(4) is the acceleration factor of y i.e step input? so why did you use it in the function script as a step input?

Comment: I also tried to generate the codes but, i kept getting the error that the x is not defined. my codes are m1=500;
c=1200;
k1=25000;
D2x = (1/m1)*(-k1*x-c*Dx+k1*y+c*Dy)
[t,X] = ode45(@diff_eqn,[0 20],[0; 0; 0; 0]);
[dX] = diff_eqn(t,X)
D2x = diff(X(:,2))./diff(t);
D2x = [0; D2x];
D2y = zeros(size(D2x));
D2y(t>=2) = 0.5;
plot(t,[D2y 500*D2x])
grid on
xlabel('Time [s]')
legend('D2y','m1*D2x','Location','NorthEast') with the function file that you uploaded

Comment: Please don't start a new question when you already have one pretty much exactly the same open, for which you have an answer, which you haven't accepted. I spent a lot of time on this poorly asked question, extracting the lacking information from you. As I said many times before, and in answer to your latest questions, my answer matches your Simulink implementation (including the `1/m1` and `dX(4)`), it doesn't mean it's right though.